# How do I import a public key?

Tags: gnupg

When I ran an update, I get the following error.

```
GPG error: http://cran.wustl.edu maverick/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
```

Therefore, I ran the following code and get the following error message:

```
$ gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv 51716619E084DAB9
gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
gpg: key E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

How do I set a public key that works or what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**1)** You can try this:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E084DAB9
```

and then:

```
 gpg --export --armor E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update
```

**2)** If "1" doesn't work ([you're not alone](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1694202)) then you can use this:

"Some people have reported difficulties using [the first approach]. The issue was usually related to a firewall blocking port 11371. An alternative approach is to search for the key at http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/ and copy the key to a plain text file, say key.txt. Then, feed the key to apt-key with

```
sudo apt-key add key.txt
```

"

As explained [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).

To make it easy for this specific case:

Searching for **Michael Rutter** lead us to:

```
Public Key Server -- Get ``0x51716619e084dab9 ''

-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: SKS 1.0.10
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=BF1w
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I) Copy this to a txt file:

```
gedit ~/Michael.txt
```

II) Run this

```
sudo apt-key add ~/Michael.txt && rm ~/Michel.txt
```

Also [EvilPhoenix](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/evilphoenix) has "got a script that you can install which can allow you to execute the functions described here in a much easier one-line command, its part of a Launchpad project [he] started, the PPA for it is located [here](http://launchpad.net/~addgpg-apt-developers/+archive/ppa).
 Its written in Bash, but that is more than enough of a requirement for it to qualify.
 Its compatible with all versions of Ubuntu Lucid and later."

Comment: Same error message with the first command. The second command read a lot of package lists it seems.

Comment: That's because the second command included `sudo apt-get update` in there.  The first two parts of that second command  are the important ones: `gpg --export --armor E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add - `.  This command is what will actually have the pubkey work with apt.

Comment: I've got a script that you can install which can allow you to execute the functions described here in a much easier one-line command, its part of a Launchpad project I started, the PPA for it is located here: https://launchpad.net/~addgpg-apt-developers/+archive/ppa .   Its written in Bash, but that is more than enough of a requirement for it to qualify.  It should be run as superuser, probably, but its compatible with all versions of Ubuntu Lucid and later (i'm still testing on older releases).

Comment: Sure, I've been credited for my script, you're allowed to spread that.  As long as you give me the credit which is deserved (which you did) ;)

Comment: Hi guys, I tried suggested solution 1 but I still get the same error. Also when I tried part 2, I copied the content in http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x51716619E084DAB9 in a nano text file on my main directory and ran the command sudo apt-key add ~/Michael.txt  . I have the error:                                                                 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: Yes but now there's a new process where you can't even use `apt-key add` and you have to use `gpg` instead, but current [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-apt-key-and-add-apt-repository-deprecation-using-gpg-to-add-external-repositories-on-ubuntu-22-04) doesn't mention how to dis-assemble the `gpg` command to work from a plain text key, or even an unarmoured key, in the local file system.

Comment: Neither works for me. I almost tried everything I found on the Internet lol

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 51716619E084DAB9
```

Answer (score 7):

To add apt-keys you must use:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

Comment: This was the easiest way to get the key added when my corporate firewall blocked the default port 11371. Thanks!