# my update manager say "Requires installation of untrusted packages"

Tags: update-manager

i am new to linux and have little to some of information on commands at this point. I have managed to install ubuntu 10.10 about a 4 days ago and have successfully installed all the updates that same day- via the terminal. Now today i got 5 updates and wil not let me install them by any commands i give it. upadate manager say requires installation of untrusted packages. the terminal say:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.UWSzw2Lg76 --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection refused
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

can someone help me fix this.

Comment: Did you see this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center

Answer (score 4):

Run the command directly from the terminal emulator of your choice (personally, and as an example, I use Konsole). The command is `sudo apt-get upgrade` OR`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Run [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) for more information.

Comment: It's really unfortunate that this is the user experience Ubuntu has for this situation. Unhelpful error message, no explanation of what is going on, no option to continue, have to open terminal (disclaimer: I work in terminal all day long) to do anything more.

Comment: You say to run one or the other of `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but running `sudo apt-get update` *followed by* `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` also makes sense. Also, `sudo apt-get update` should be run before running either of those commands.