# "not authenticated sources" warning on apparently safe packages, Ubuntu Update Manager

Tags: software-center, update-manager

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 for about 8 months. My machine was disconnected for a couple of weeks. Am now connected, and Update Manager has 23 updates waiting. But I get a warning "The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources."

I've tried several, single updates, and so far all have this warning. E.g., for just the SSL development libraries, header files and documentation, the "Details" panel shows: 
libssl-dev

I see that a very similar question at [my update manager say "Requires installation of untrusted packages"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123818/my-update-manager-say-requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages) was answered in terms of terminal commands.

What is happening here? If I go the command-line route, must I abandon the Update Manager permanently?

Answer (score 1):

> The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources

That could mean you have missing authentication keys. To check, open system settings - Software & Updates. Then go to Other Software tab. Uncheck any sources you don't use. Then you need to make sure you have a key (Authentication tab) for each for each source. If you are missing any keys, that is probably the source of the error. You would then go to the corresponding PPA website, click the verification signature, click it again, save the page as a text document. Then go back to the Authentication tab and import it.

After those steps, close Software & Updates and launch Software Update again.

> If I go the command-line route, must I abandon the Update Manager permanently?

No, it will still be available. The Software Updater gui will automatically refresh if you modify any sources or applications.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question; will try what you suggest.

Comment: Interesting. I use XFCE (old machine), and found the tab you specify at Applications Menu | Settings | Update Manager | Settings | Other Software (tab). I unchecked all but the main Ubuntu volumes at ppa.launchpad.net, ran update, and it went fine, no warnings. I then added the volumes I had unchecked: two Canonical Partners and two Independent volumes, plus an Epson volume for printer drivers. Again, ran update, went fine.

Comment: So, *without* needing to modify any authentication keys, I am now updated from all volumes. I don't understand how a key could go from authenticated to not-authenticated and back again. Would like to understand this better; meanwhile, does this sound like I'm back to a fully and safely updated OS?

Comment: Maybe the database just needed to be synced again (funky error none the less). It sounds like you are good to go. If you want guarantees, upgrade to ubuntu 14.