# Unable to install software updates in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with “unauthenticated sources” errors in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center)

I'm trying to install software updates but I always get this error.

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
The action would require the installation of packages from unauthenticated sources.
Details : gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gnome-tweak-tool libmutter0 mutter-common
```

I don't know what it's asking me to do. Please help.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo apt-get update` in your question?

Comment: Did you check this ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center

Answer (score 2):

This actually solved the problem:

sudo apt-get clean

cd /var/lib/apt

sudo mv lists lists.old

sudo mkdir -p lists/partial

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

Many thanks!

I got the answer here: [How do I deal with "unauthenticated sources" errors in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center)

Comment: Just "sudo apt-get clean" and "sudo apt-get update" was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to  select a differnent mirror. Run

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

In the **Ubuntu Software** tab, **Download from**, select via the drop-down an other server. After this, run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.