# unable to install VLC player through ubuntu software centre

Tags: apt, software-center, vlc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with “unauthenticated sources” errors in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center)

i am using ubuntu 12.04 version. i am trying to install VLC media player through software centre. But I cant. Pop up message shows that "**The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources."**

please guide me how to do install it?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution is that you download the installation package from [VLC offical site](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

And install the downloaded package by double-click.