# Not able install paint tool in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-one, paint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I deal with “unauthenticated sources” errors in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center)
> [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I am using ubuntu 10.10, here i am not able install any paint tool. If i try to install some tool, it will show below message in a dialog box.

```
 Requires installation of untrusted packages

 The action would require the installation of packages from not
 authenticated sources.
```

Please suggest some paint tool along with installation steps.

Also i have tried **$ sudo apt-get update**
but it is showing like below

> ...
>
> Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
>
> Fetched 198B in 22s (9B/s)
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz
> 404  Not Found
>
> ...

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 is End-of-Life and the Extras repository does not have any software for this version of Ubuntu anymore. Upgrade to a newer stable release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any PPAs you added, and switching from the Indian mirrors to another mirror using the Software Sources tool.

Comment: Exactly, i don't know what all PPAs i need to remove?

Comment: 1) The error is not about PPAs. 2) Mirror says: 404 *correctly because it's EOL'd*

Comment: EOL means End-Of-Life, that release of Ubuntu is no longer supported and the mirrors don't contain packages for it any more.