# keep getting internal system errors and can not see the desktop

Tags: grub2, apt, .desktop

I have found quite a few topics within this problem, but didn't really find a clear answer.
I have updated my Ubuntu. The update I have installed Ubuntu update center said it had some unothorized installs. I have read, that people get these messages, but what you need to do is run sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get upgrade. So that was what I did. After I restarted the computer, I received this "Internal system problem". Tried to restart computer quite few times, but still the same. The thing is that I can not see the desktop as well, no icons, no nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A first attempt, the way would try personally:

Do you get a login prompt if you hold `CTRL`+`SHIFT` and hit `F1` ? - if that is not possible, try to get into 'Recovery mode' from the grub menu (hit ESC immediately at the end of BIOS displays to see it, if it isn't shown automatically).

In recovery mode first do `fsck`, then
`enable networking`, and finally
`root prompt`.

After either of the above try
`sudo apt-get check` at the prompt.

If that goes well then follow up with
`sudo apt-get update` (will scroll a lot of text) and
`sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center  is also relevant - it does contain things to try if the above doesn't help.

Comment: I could manage to turn the recovery mode and did the fsck without problems. Running Enable networking I had this error saying "couldn't din'd support for device at....(many numbers): not supported by any plugin.
Running the root prompt I get error again. running sudo apt-get update would stuck somehwere at 8% and would move anywhere

Comment: That means that you do not have a working network connection - you will not be able to (re)download new content/packages. I'd suggest you still go to the root prompt and try the remainder of what I have written above - it might actually fix at least the networking. If you still have trouble after it: Then also check the information behind the link ^-- in the first comment. Try to match what you see with the info and try out any recommendations/commands.

Comment: I tried your way again, it didn't work out. Tried the same command lines with CTRL+ALT+F2. the update and upgrade worked this time but didn't really help. The error that I had just after the update, was about the compiz. Maybe I can restore it somehow using CTLR+ALT+F2? Maybe reinstalling Ubuntu would help?

Comment: Reinstalling Ubuntu might be the "easy" way, if it works out ;-) - but looking into the details of the trouble with `compiz` **might** be quicker - or not ;-)

Comment: So I have managed to open compiz by using a few commands in cltr+alt+f2. And now I have opened web browser as well (I did right click on desktop, which surprisingly worked and opened a movie using mozzila). The thing is that I can find quite few solutions about not seeing launcher, but most of them needs terminal, which I can not open using cltr+alt+t not via launcher. How can I get my launcher back when I have compiz on, but not the terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16250/discussion-between-user288690-and-hannu).