# Software Update: This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

When trying to install packages through the software updater on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS I get following error:

[image: Software Updater error]

It's about these packages:
[image: Software Updates packages]

I have selected following settings from where to install updates from:
[image: Software & Updates settings]

I have run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

sudo apt-get update gives following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
```

sudo apt-get upgrade gives following output:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglapi-mesa libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa libosmesa6 liboxideqt-qmlplugin
  liboxideqtcore0 libwayland-egl1-mesa libxatracker2 linux-generic
  linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic linux-headers-generic-pae
  linux-image-generic linux-image-generic-pae oxideqt-codecs
  python-cupshelpers system-config-printer-gnome
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
```

---

**UPDATE**

With question [How do I deal with "unauthenticated sources" errors in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center)

issueing following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

still gives following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
```

Followed the second answer:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A902DDA375E52366
sudo apt-get update
```

but receive following error:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

and apt-get update doesn't correct the problem

Comment: what is the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @g_p I added the output. I'm guessing the GPG error might be the problem?

Comment: @g_p Still doesn't work, I edited the question

Comment: As you don't  have GPG error now, You would not get the warning you were getting earlier. For Duplicate sources.list warning see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry) post.

Comment: I am having the same problem with 14.10, I cannot upgrade the "Ubuntu Base" updates, they are a bunch of Kernel stuff.

Comment: Beyond the erratic list of commands, the answers reflect very little on how to address the question's topic

Answer (score 12):

You could run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Voilà! Worked for me at first time!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the duplicate entry in your sources.list file:

Open it in an editor with root/sudo rights e.g:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and remove the duplicate line (does not matter which):

```
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
```

Then use ctrl-x to exit (y to save).
Do an apt-get update and upgrade as you normally would.

Comment: There were no duplicate entries. The answer from desgua http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry did the trick

Comment: Ah OK, I missed the edit/comment. Are all your problems solved then ? If so, answer your own question with what you did and mark solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Comment those lines, of which this error is producing.

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) an run the following commands.

Change to the `/etc/apt` directory:

```
cd /etc/apt/
```

Edit the file `sources.list`:

```
sudo nano sources.list
```

Comment the lines with `#` symbol which is mentioned in the error log.

Once update the `sources.list` file, upgrade your software by using the following command line.

```
sudo apt-get clean    
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open 'Software & Updates' and go to 'Other software'.
2. Uncheck the software which is showing error while updating.
3. Refresh and rerun the update.

Answer (score -2):

Hi best is that whenever you face this problem use the terminal to know what actually stopping it so open terminal and use below command

```
sudo apt-get clean    
sudo apt-get update
```

Update command will show you the URL or Package which is creating a problem, generally this is due to unreliable package like when I ran this I got below error on terminal

```
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
W: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
```

So it mean http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb was potential harmful for my computer and that is where you then need to UNCHECK this from update setting panel OR you can update your installation  file.

Comment: *http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb was potential harmful*: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb is the official repository of Google Chrome. I don't see how it was harmful for you. GPG errors generally mean you have added "alien" repositories to the system. Those "alien" repositories may or may not be harmful depending on the source and developer.