# Software Updater requires installation of untrusted packages from unauthenticated sources

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I use Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop Edition.
Now I see Software Updater's message that it must be updated.
Then I get a message

```
requires installation of untrusted packages from unauthenticated sources
```

What's going on here? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run these commands

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

[reference](https://askubuntu.com/q/85641/294611)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply!

It gets stranger by the minute. I'd initiated Software Updater, but it just found "Ubuntu base" updates and successfully installed them.
No mention of Unity Tweak tool. See, before that I didn't initiate the update. It'd started by itself. So... I don't know.

Comment: @Gregory if software update runs by it self its not strange, it runs after every specific time, you can change it in `Software and Updates` program

Comment: The "strange" part wasn't about the fact that the Updater ran by itself. The "strange" thing to me was the fact that now all of a sudden Unity Tweak Tool doesn't even ask to be updated at all!

Comment: @Gregory open `Software and Updates` program and in tab called `Ubuntu Software` check first 4 options and then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and tell me did you get the update of tweak tool or not. note: you will see update tweak tool in terminal itself

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Those 4 options are already checked there. Unity Tweak Tool update has miraculously disappeared. Hope the issue is solved. If anything, I will follow your guidance.

Comment: @Gregory besides that, if your problem is solved you should accept my answer :)