# Install/upgrade without verification[y/n]

Tags: upgrade, software-installation

Whenever we update or install some software it ask "Install/upgrade without verification[y/n]". If you type 'y' everything continues smoothly,but upon typing 'n' it breaks the operation and says "some operations can’t be completed".
So if 'n' breaks the operations then there no need of asking for installation without verification. My question is what is the motive behind not removing this [y/n] ?

Answer (score 0):

`[Y/n]` is a choice given to you. `Y` is for yes, `n` is for no. You're telling it to stop operation by typing `n`. So, It is perfectly rational behavior to stop the operation if you commanded it to do so.

That question is asked when you try to install packages from unauthentic repositories, giving you an option to install packages even if those aren't verified. You can continue by typing `Y`. So, your saying

> So if 'n' breaks the operations then there no need of asking for installation without verification.

is not right. There can be some users who want to install packages without verification.

See this question for details on installing packages with "unauthenticated source"

- [How do I deal with "unauthenticated sources" errors in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center)