# Can't update packages -- either "Failed to download package files. Check internet..." or "requires installation from unauthenticated sources"

Tags: apt, package-management, internet, connection

I first got this

```
Failed to download package files. Check internet connection
```

error and tried the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error) that seems to work for most others who had the same problem...changing the download location. I've tried several different servers to no effect. I also tried the second solution in the link above (having apt make a new source list file).

More recently, the error has instead been "installation requires installation from unauthenticated sources." The first solution in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center) is the same as the second solution from the first link from above and makes no difference in my situation. Before I start adding public keys or any other solution, I figured it would be best to post my output specifically and see what the community has to say.

Here is my [output](http://pastebin.com/qkWEGedK) for `apt-get update`.

Here is my [output](http://pastebin.com/bidNYR1N) for `apt-get upgrade`.

I don't have a high enough reputation to post more than two links, so here is the output for `/etc/apt/sources.list` directly:

```
~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe main multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe main multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

## added myself -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630434/graphviz-installation-ubuntu-14-04
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
# deb-src http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
# deb-src http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed multiverse restricted universe main
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed multiverse restricted universe main #Added by software-properties
```

Based on the 6th error from the bottom of the output for `apt-get update`, it seems at least one of the issues is the inability to authenticate some package from Nvidia (probably the cuda repository that I installed anyway just now -- was that terribly stupid of me to do?).

Not sure what to do next and would appreciate any guidance! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Not sure why you add lucid repository to trusty but anyway should already know what are you doing. Lucid comes to its EndOfLife and its repository was moved to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ so change those line to:

  ```
  deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main
  deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main
  ```
- For second error about cuda package authentication, your system is missing that nvidia repository GPG public key, add it using

  ```
  wget -q http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
  ```