# E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Suite): Installing R

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I have tried installing R (for the first time on Ubuntu) using [this blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/).

First three steps ran fine:

```
sudo echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntuxenial/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

I got an 'OK'

Problem occurs in 4th step:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I looked up the file, which said, at line 54:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntuxenial/ xenial
```

The file was unable to be modified.

At first, I thought it was because I couldn't have access to public key so I tried the steps suggested by the first answer: [How do I import a public key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36507/how-do-i-import-a-public-key/36510#36510?newreg=d42bc1d282714397aa8dd6a25d9999f7)
However

I also tested to see if it was a firewall issue by switching from my company connection to my phone hotspot and repeating the installation process, same errors occurred, so I don't think its due to having blocked port 11371.

Any ideas how I can fix the issue? I'm not sure how to correct line 54 (in terms of what to write and also how to get past the text edit restrictions).

Comment: The line is wrong.

Comment: What should it say at line 54?

Comment: Remove that line. It is wrong.

Comment: The line should be of the form `deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ xenial [type]` where [type] is contrib, main, partner, etc.

Comment: I didn't add any type.. it appears to have worked for now. will this cause any issues going forward?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Pilot6 and @OrganicMarble for the suggestion. just for if anyone else is experiencing the issue:
I ended up using

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

which helped me override permissions restriction and modify the file.

Just changed line 54 to

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial[type]
```

Comment: I just noticed that. Was going to make an answer ))