# Ubuntu updates - check your internet connection

Tags: command-line, updates, steam

Have a problem - can't update Ubuntu. Via Software updater i have "Check your internet connection" message. Via Terminal:

```
    sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease [2 861 B]       
Get:3 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]      
Err:2 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease 
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:5 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:6 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [102 kB]
Get:7 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [269 kB]
Get:8 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:9 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8 016 B]
Get:10 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12,5 kB]  
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41,6 kB]         
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17,1 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                  
W: GPG error: http://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
E: The repository 'http://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've tried one solution, which is:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.k7KsmtABvG/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7
gpg: key F24AEA9FB05498B7: "Valve Corporation <linux@steampowered.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

And this does nothing. Pls send help! I am out of ideas! So does Google!

Comment: Please see the long answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992799/warning-apt-key-is-deprecated-manage-keyring-files-in-trusted-gpg-d-instead/71384057#71384057

Comment: Found solution:
1) go to repo.steampowered.com/steam
2) download steam.gpt
3) open terminal, type: sudo nautilus
4) navigate to /usr/share/keyrings/
5) move steam.gpt to kayrings folder
6) run sudo apt-get update
7) profit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import a public key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36507/how-do-i-import-a-public-key)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)